# phenny/jenni IRC bot programming

Tags: python, chat, irc, bots

I'm checking them out, but not at all understanding how I'd do several things:

1. How, after a user joins the channel, `jenni` sends him a welcome message
2. How to write a module in general
3. Why `.block list nick` or any of the `.block` commands just fail (no output)

Also, do memos carry over if jenbot goes offline? Where is the database?

Comment: Only thing that I can say to you about IRC and the first point of your question is that, on IRC there are several events. One of these is "on join". So, when the trigger "on join" is activated, the script will do something. In this way, any IRC bot could send a messagge.

Comment: @DonCallisto I understand, but I don't understand how to call the `privmsg` command.

Comment: I've never interfaced python with irc, sorry. I just say to you all I remember about IRC programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have my code on this computer, but try this:

```
jenni.write(['PRIVMSG','target_nick'],"Write your message here")
```

Comment: That's the correct irc command according to the leftover bits of code I have laying around from my jenni hackage the last week.

Comment: What I mean is stuff like `/kick user`

Comment: jenni.write(['KICK', channel, nick, reason])

https://github.com/myano/jenni/blob/master/modules/adminchannel.py

Answer (score 1):

`jenni.msg(nick, "Hello world!")` -- this will send a private message to the 'nick'
`jenni.say("Hello world!")` -- this will send a message to where ever jenni received the command (in PM or a channel)
`jenni.reply("Hello world!")` -- this will highlight the user that triggered the command

1. You'll need to script a module to act on a trigger for this to happen. phenny/jenni does not do this by default.
2. [How to create your own phenny/jenni module](https://github.com/myano/jenni/wiki/How-to-create-a-phenny-module)
3. It's `.blocks list nick` and `.blocks list hostmask`

Also phenny/jenni from their respective main repositories on github do not currently have the ability to handle memos from MemoServ. You'd want to script something up for that. The memos don't disappear, they stay on the IRC server. (at least this is how MemoServ behaves on freenode)